# What closure for strict transform of affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, blowup

Given $\pi:X\to \mathbb{A}^2$, the blowup of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the origin, I am trying to calculate the strict transform of $Y=\mathbb{V}(y^2-x^2(x+1))$, which has been defined as the *closure* of $\pi^{-1}(Y\setminus\{0,0\})$ inside $X$.

What is meant by taking the closure here? If I am not mistaken, the preimage $\pi^{-1}(Y\setminus\{0,0\})$ is contained in a patch of $X$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$ - can I work in this patch and take an affine closure? Do I have to take some sort of projective closure?

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. $X$ is a topological space, so we can take the closure of any subset. After that I guess the question could be what scheme structure you want to put on it, but the word "closure" should not be ambiguous.

Comment: A formatting tip: \setminus is best for writing something like $Y\setminus \{0,0\}$. I've updated your post with this.

Comment: @CaptainLama I see. Any hints on how to actually find the closure? Viewing points in $X$ as $((x,y),(z_0,z_1))$ the vanishing of $y^2-x^2(x+1)$ is closed and contains $Y$, but is it the closure?

Comment: If you're trying to find the strict transform, there are several other posts on this site with explanations. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112767/in-algebraic-geometry-how-do-you-explicitly-find-the-strict-transform) for example.